# PopupMenu dismiss without checking the selected checkbox item

Tags: android

When I click on an item of my Popupmenu, the item doesn't get checked and the menu disappear instantly. Is there a way at least to get the item checked ?

```
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getActivity(), v);
MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.filtering_menu, popup.getMenu());
popup.getMenu().findItem(R.id.filter_old).setChecked(hide_old);
popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
});
popup.show();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By posting this question, I got the answer, I just need to check the item myself after the click event:

```
item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
```