# How use popup checkbox and dismiss?

Tags: android, popup, android-checkbox, popupmenu

I'm exhausted. I try select my checkbox, but popup always close after my change. When I searched information about this problem, I found these links:

1) [PopupMenu dismiss without checking the selected checkbox item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22515502/popupmenu-dismiss-without-checking-the-selected-checkbox-item)

2) [How to prevent popup menu from closing on checkbox click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29726039/how-to-prevent-popup-menu-from-closing-on-checkbox-click/)

3) [Menu item click hides popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32948701/menu-item-click-hides-popup?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Nothing of these didn't help me with my problem. This is my code:

```
    private void openPopupMenu(View view) {
    final PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, view);
    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.popup_push:
                    item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                case R.id.popup_delete_store:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), item.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.activity_stores_popup_menu);
    popupMenu.show();
}
```

Comment: Where is the suggested `popup.show()` after clicking an item? Did you try that?

Comment: @MuratK. I set `popup.show()`  after clicking, but result not changed.

Comment: you should return false if you don't want to popup to dismiss

Comment: @Farid In example where I have `return true` - like result my experiments. At first I used `result false`